# Laravel 5.7 Vue.js 2 not working in Edge and IE 11

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, babeljs, laravel-mix

I've created a Laravel project 5.7 and i've used a lot of vue and vuex in this one and when i finished the project I was surprised that it's not working at all neither in IE 11 nor MS Edge.

I searched the web and lots of people mentioned "babel" term which is totally new for me, I installed it in my project but it's not working because I couldn't configure it with Laravel Mix.

After trying and installing packages nothing worked for me.

Here's what I did:

- npm install --save @babel/polyfill
- require("@babel/polyfill") in the top off public/js/app.js file
- in webpack.mix.js file I changed this

  ```
  mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')  
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  mix.babel('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
  ```

I ran `npm run dev` but it didn't work.

What I need, since I'm totally new to Laravel Mix and this "babel" thing, is a configuration guide to the whole process.

[picture of edge console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9rMc.png)

Comment: I believe babel is used in older laravel apps. Vue should just work in IE. Which errors do you get in ie?

Comment: @SanderVisser i updated it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all of your vue components which are rendered inside of blade are not self closing. E.g. `<vue-comment />` instead use `<vue-comment></vue-comment>` this is an issue I had which I tracked down to that.

Hopefully this is all it is.